# Microsoft Graph refresh token in C#

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

I use the following code form Graph Client using for requesting several calendar informations.

But according to following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens

and the documentation of GetToken() in ClientSecretCredential class

> "Obtains a token from the Azure Active Directory service, using the
> specified client secret to authenticate. This method is called
> automatically by Azure SDK client libraries. You may call this method
> directly, but you must also handle token caching and token
> refreshing."

It seems to be auto-refresh yes ?
Following code part is my instantiation:

```
TenantID = tenantID;
ClientID = clientID;
TenantShortName = tenantShortName;
ClientSecret = clientSecret;
TokenCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(TenantID, ClientID, ClientSecret);

GraphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(TokenCredential, Scopes);
```

Anyone have and idea please ?

Comment: and what is the problem that is occurring?

Comment: Just print the token information to console and check if it is the same token over several calls.

Answer (score 0):

At first, as what you know, when we want to call Microsoft graph api, we need to obtain an access token first and then send it along with the request in the request header so that we can call api successfully.

And access token has a much shorter life cycle, so we need to re-generate a new access token manually or we can use refresh token to renew an access token. But not all Azure AD flows can generate refresh tokens. Per my knowledge, only [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-certificate-credential) can generate a refresh token. And I'm sure client credential flow can't generate a refresh token, because when we want to generate refresh token, we need to add `offline_access` in the scope, but client credential flow can only set scope like `xxx/.default`.

[image]

And your code snippet indicates that you are using client credential flow. Since Microsoft provide graph SDK, so it's unnecessary for you to get the token when you use SDK, it's only necessary when you are trying to manage a `httpclient` to call api. And this is why you see from the document mentioned "handle token caching and token refreshing". This doesn't mean the token will be refreshed automatically, this means you need to manually generate a new access token, execute your code again to renew the auth provider or generate a new token if you need to get the token.